# Which of the following keeps a user logged in when they are browsing a website and create new tabs?

Tags: http, security, session

I had a programming interview this morning was asked which of the following answers maintains a user's logged in state as they browse a website and even open new tabs:

1. HTTP cookies
2. HTTP keep-alive
3. Websockets
4. HTML local storage

I did not think that any of them were suitable answers.

Cookies can be used, but it is not secure.

Keep-alive is about keeping the connection open to allow for greater network efficiency. Maybe if logged in requires a constant server connection this could work, but it doesn't seem to generally fit the use case.

Websocket is for back and forth communication, not maintaining login.

Localstorage could again be used, but like cookies, it has no data security whatsoever and again seems inappropriate.

I told the interviewer sessions with a token on the clientside as the data is stored server-side, but he wanted me to choose from the list of options. I chose localstorage but I am not sure whether that was the correct choice. What am I missing? Am I misunderstanding some concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer "1. HTTP cookies" is correct. And cookies can be implemented in a secure manner. Please refer to [OWASP ASVS](https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/raw/master/4.0/OWASP%20Application%20Security%20Verification%20Standard%204.0-en.pdf) chapter V3.4 Cookie-based Session Management for the details.

Local storage - as the name implies - is used for storing the data locally on the client. This storage is not shared with the server per default and should never be used to hold any confidential data whatsoever.

You are more or less right about the other points.

Comment: sometime its maintained according to the framework you use, like JSESSIONID in java, or you can do your own with keycloak and microservices... its different topic ))